# Which resolution is appropriate for resampling a raster in a specific CRS in QGIS 3.6?

Tags: interpolation, resolution, resampling, smoothing

I'm trying to resample a raster file to obtain smooth interpolated levels in EPSG:3120 - Pulkovo 1942(58) / Poland zone I projection. (following the steps in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346049/making-elevation-contours-of-raster-smoother-using-qgis/346073?noredirect=1#comment568489_346073))

**1.** Using the raster calculator with the desired values, in my case:**

```
("eu rel rez clip@1" <= 0) * 0 + 

("eu rel rez clip@1" > 0  AND "eu rel rez clip@1" <= 100) * 100 + 

("eu rel rez clip@1" > 100 AND "eu rel rez clip@1" <= 200) * 200 +

("eu rel rez clip@1" > 200 AND "eu rel rez clip@1" <= 500) * 500 +

("eu rel rez clip@1" > 500 AND "eu rel rez clip@1" <= 1000) * 1000 +

("eu rel rez clip@1" > 1000 AND "eu rel rez clip@1" <= 2000) * 2000 +

("eu rel rez clip@1" > 2000 AND "eu rel rez clip@1" <= 3000) * 3000 +

("eu rel rez clip@1" > 3000 AND "eu rel rez clip@1" <= 4000) * 4000 +

("eu rel rez clip@1" > 4000) * 4000
```

**2.** Resampling the output using *r.resamp.rst* from GRASS and selecting only the slope raster with resolution cell size *200*. The output has 270 cell size and the raster which I want to resample with a better resolution its large, so I don't want to make it lower than 200. The result was fine.

**3.** At the last step resampling output with slope raster smoothed selecting only *Resampled RST* the process failed.

[image]

---

At the Log box was this message:

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'r.resamp.rst' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-d' : False, '-t' : False, 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'aspect' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'elevation' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'ew_res' : 200, 'input' : 'C:/Users/EVO1/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b/99d7d1532ea943559ecf2828b25b1b08/OUTPUT.tif', 'maskmap' : None, 'mcurvature' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'ns_res' : 200, 'overlap' : None, 'pcurvature' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'scalex' : None, 'slope' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'smooth' : None, 'tcurvature' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'tension' : None, 'theta' : None, 'zscale' : 1 }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=sterea +lat_0=50.625 +lon_0=21.08333333333333 +k=0.9998 +x_0=4637000 +y_0=5467000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=33.4,-146.6,-76.3,-0.359,-0.053,0.844,-0.84 +units=m +no_defs"
r.external input="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\99d7d1532ea943559ecf2828b25b1b08\OUTPUT.tif" band=1 output="rast_5e20e2df51a8f6" --overwrite -o
g.region n=4498193.425429387 s=4195449.45885775 e=4428864.351231276 w=4074641.653501709 res=279.7967596600056
r.resamp.rst input=rast_5e20e2df51a8f6 ew_res=200 ns_res=200 overlap=3 zscale=1 tension=40 elevation=elevatione2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0 slope=slopee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0 aspect=aspecte2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0 pcurvature=pcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0 tcurvature=tcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0 mcurvature=mcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0 --overwrite
g.region raster=elevatione2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0
r.out.gdal -t -m input="elevatione2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\d789f7527d8042e8927b5afd12fdc4dd\elevation.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=slopee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0
r.out.gdal -t -m input="slopee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\377cec3c05c44e648efdc9e39955c2ba\slope.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=aspecte2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0
r.out.gdal -t -m input="aspecte2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\d92891c9ab184c6aae3a85628389b28b\aspect.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=pcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0
r.out.gdal -t -m input="pcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\2096a7ae869a497bb957d5c505a0aa06\pcurvature.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=tcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0
r.out.gdal -t -m input="tcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\38d094e1d46f4f6e8b8b63bb3214904c\tcurvature.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=mcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0
r.out.gdal -t -m input="mcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\e05e4cb2787744b48f901376b878edf8\mcurvature.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Executing <C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=sterea +lat_0=50.625 +lon_0=21.08333333333333 +k=0.9998 +x_0=4637000 +y_0=5467000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=33.4,-146.6,-76.3,-0.359,-0.053,0.844,-0.84 +units=m +no_defs"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.external input="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\99d7d1532ea943559ecf2828b25b1b08\OUTPUT.tif" band=1 output="rast_5e20e2df51a8f6" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Reading band 1 of 1...
Link to raster map <rast_5e20e2df51a8f6> created.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region n=4498193.425429387 s=4195449.45885775 e=4428864.351231276 w=4074641.653501709 res=279.7967596600056
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.resamp.rst input=rast_5e20e2df51a8f6 ew_res=200 ns_res=200 overlap=3 zscale=1 tension=40 elevation=elevatione2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0 slope=slopee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0 aspect=aspecte2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0 pcurvature=pcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0 tcurvature=tcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0 mcurvature=mcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0 --overwrite
Processing all selected output files will require
61.37 MB of disk space for temp files.
Temporarily changing the region to desired resolution ...
Changing back to the original region ...
Percent complete:
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
dnorm in ressegm after grid before out2= 3626.603691
dnorm in mainc after grid before out1= 3626.603691
dnorm in mainc after grid before out2= 3626.603691
color map written
r.resamp.rst complete.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=elevatione2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="elevatione2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\d789f7527d8042e8927b5afd12fdc4dd\elevation.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <Float32>
Input raster map contains cells with NULL-value (no-data). The value -1.#IND will be used to represent no-data values in the input map. You can specify a nodata value with the nodata option.
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal complete. File <C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\d789f7527d8042e8927b5afd12fdc4dd\elevation.tif> created.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=slopee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="slopee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\377cec3c05c44e648efdc9e39955c2ba\slope.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <Float32>
Input raster map contains cells with NULL-value (no-data). The value -1.#IND will be used to represent no-data values in the input map. You can specify a nodata value with the nodata option.
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal complete. File <C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\377cec3c05c44e648efdc9e39955c2ba\slope.tif> created.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=aspecte2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="aspecte2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\d92891c9ab184c6aae3a85628389b28b\aspect.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <Float32>
Input raster map contains cells with NULL-value (no-data). The value -1.#IND will be used to represent no-data values in the input map. You can specify a nodata value with the nodata option.
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal complete. File <C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\d92891c9ab184c6aae3a85628389b28b\aspect.tif> created.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=pcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="pcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\2096a7ae869a497bb957d5c505a0aa06\pcurvature.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <Float32>
Input raster map contains cells with NULL-value (no-data). The value -1.#IND will be used to represent no-data values in the input map. You can specify a nodata value with the nodata option.
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal complete. File <C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\2096a7ae869a497bb957d5c505a0aa06\pcurvature.tif> created.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=tcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="tcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\38d094e1d46f4f6e8b8b63bb3214904c\tcurvature.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <Float32>
Input raster map contains cells with NULL-value (no-data). The value -1.#IND will be used to represent no-data values in the input map. You can specify a nodata value with the nodata option.
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal complete. File <C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\38d094e1d46f4f6e8b8b63bb3214904c\tcurvature.tif> created.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=mcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="mcurvaturee2ff9d11ae6c4c7b845694b70c2b18c0" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\e05e4cb2787744b48f901376b878edf8\mcurvature.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <Float32>
Input raster map contains cells with NULL-value (no-data). The value -1.#IND will be used to represent no-data values in the input map. You can specify a nodata value with the nodata option.
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal complete. File <C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\e05e4cb2787744b48f901376b878edf8\mcurvature.tif> created.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 64.25 seconds
Results:
{'aspect': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'elevation': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'mcurvature': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'pcurvature': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'slope': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'tcurvature': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'r.resamp.rst' finished
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'r.resamp.rst' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-d' : False, '-t' : False, 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'aspect' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'elevation' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'ew_res' : 200, 'input' : 'C:/Users/EVO1/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b/99d7d1532ea943559ecf2828b25b1b08/OUTPUT.tif', 'maskmap' : None, 'mcurvature' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'ns_res' : 200, 'overlap' : None, 'pcurvature' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'scalex' : None, 'slope' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'smooth' : 'C:/Users/EVO1/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b/377cec3c05c44e648efdc9e39955c2ba/slope.tif', 'tcurvature' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'tension' : None, 'theta' : None, 'zscale' : 1 }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=sterea +lat_0=50.625 +lon_0=21.08333333333333 +k=0.9998 +x_0=4637000 +y_0=5467000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=33.4,-146.6,-76.3,-0.359,-0.053,0.844,-0.84 +units=m +no_defs"
r.external input="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\99d7d1532ea943559ecf2828b25b1b08\OUTPUT.tif" band=1 output="rast_5e20e4dc9df787" --overwrite -o
r.external input="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\377cec3c05c44e648efdc9e39955c2ba\slope.tif" band=1 output="rast_5e20e4dc9df788" --overwrite -o
g.region n=4498193.42542939 s=4195449.45885775 e=4428864.35123128 w=4074641.653501709 res=279.7967596600056
r.resamp.rst input=rast_5e20e4dc9df787 smooth=rast_5e20e4dc9df788 ew_res=200 ns_res=200 overlap=3 zscale=1 tension=40 elevation=elevation50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31 slope=slope50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31 aspect=aspect50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31 pcurvature=pcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31 tcurvature=tcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31 mcurvature=mcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31 --overwrite
g.region raster=elevation50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31
r.out.gdal -t -m input="elevation50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\dec023a15a8a4e6bb3ca86c1b6a3cf80\elevation.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=slope50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31
r.out.gdal -t -m input="slope50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\85dd4c6bde424b19bbed0889c54853c5\slope.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=aspect50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31
r.out.gdal -t -m input="aspect50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\eceeb34fc9b64b88b41a66e409b5a61a\aspect.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=pcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31
r.out.gdal -t -m input="pcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\aeb6452f6e5048b18df867122250328b\pcurvature.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=tcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31
r.out.gdal -t -m input="tcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\dd88c5727c4e4df39027b4a4423c9734\tcurvature.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
g.region raster=mcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31
r.out.gdal -t -m input="mcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\0f8c966290a649c0b34ac89566bc8bda\mcurvature.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Executing <C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=sterea +lat_0=50.625 +lon_0=21.08333333333333 +k=0.9998 +x_0=4637000 +y_0=5467000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=33.4,-146.6,-76.3,-0.359,-0.053,0.844,-0.84 +units=m +no_defs"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.external input="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\99d7d1532ea943559ecf2828b25b1b08\OUTPUT.tif" band=1 output="rast_5e20e4dc9df787" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Reading band 1 of 1...
Link to raster map <rast_5e20e4dc9df787> created.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.external input="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\377cec3c05c44e648efdc9e39955c2ba\slope.tif" band=1 output="rast_5e20e4dc9df788" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Reading band 1 of 1...
Link to raster map <rast_5e20e4dc9df788> created.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region n=4498193.42542939 s=4195449.45885775 e=4428864.35123128 w=4074641.653501709 res=279.7967596600056
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.resamp.rst input=rast_5e20e4dc9df787 smooth=rast_5e20e4dc9df788 ew_res=200 ns_res=200 overlap=3 zscale=1 tension=40 elevation=elevation50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31 slope=slope50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31 aspect=aspect50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31 pcurvature=pcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31 tcurvature=tcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31 mcurvature=mcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31 --overwrite
ERROR: Map <rast_5e20e4dc9df788> is the wrong resolution
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=elevation50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31
ERROR: Raster map <elevation50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31> not found
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="elevation50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\dec023a15a8a4e6bb3ca86c1b6a3cf80\elevation.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR: Raster map or group <elevation50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31> not found
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=slope50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31
ERROR: Raster map <slope50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31> not found
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="slope50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\85dd4c6bde424b19bbed0889c54853c5\slope.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR: Raster map or group <slope50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31> not found
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=aspect50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31
ERROR: Raster map <aspect50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31> not found
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="aspect50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\eceeb34fc9b64b88b41a66e409b5a61a\aspect.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR: Raster map or group <aspect50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31> not found
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=pcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31
ERROR: Raster map <pcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31> not found
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="pcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\aeb6452f6e5048b18df867122250328b\pcurvature.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR: Raster map or group <pcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31> not found
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=tcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31
ERROR: Raster map <tcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31> not found
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="tcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\dd88c5727c4e4df39027b4a4423c9734\tcurvature.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR: Raster map or group <tcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31> not found
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=mcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31
ERROR: Raster map <mcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31> not found
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="mcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31" output="C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\0f8c966290a649c0b34ac89566bc8bda\mcurvature.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR: Raster map or group <mcurvature50e20c2b824d4c5f8794b2c9d01d5d31> not found
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\EVO1\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Press any key to continue . . .
Execution completed in 3.23 seconds
Results:
{'aspect': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'elevation': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'mcurvature': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'pcurvature': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'slope': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'tcurvature': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/EVO1/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_71aaa5f6019240ce86885c11a27fc76b/dec023a15a8a4e6bb3ca86c1b6a3cf80/elevation.tif</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

How to find who's the correct resolution for this projection ?

Comment: Seems like there is a mix of resolutions there. Try exporting _Output_ layer (between steps `1` and `2`) to a _200x200_ cellsize, by selecting the layer, right click, Save As to a GeoTIFF with the _200x200_ cell size. Then start the first _r.resamp.rst_ (step `2`) with that GeoTIFF. The slope raster must be _200x200_ also. Then will not be mixed resolutions when running the algorithm again (step `3`) with the saved GeoTIFF _Input_ and the Slope _Smooth_ raster layers.

Comment: I follow your steps but still have a problem with the result Resampling RST. The algorithm finished but the map look like a mosaic filter ( https://prnt.sc/qp9ios ). In the log box its a message :WARNING: Quantization file for raster map <mcurvature17819ea1474b412cb291e6008e6280c9@PERMANENT> is empty.

Comment: The resolution error was solved. But the question about what resolution is appropiate for your map is a bit broad. About the look of your new map, I don't know how your classified map looks. About the quantization warning I also don't know if it has something to do with how your new map looks.

Comment: I want a printable map in B0 with a good resolution looking like a vector map instead of a raster with blurred contour lines. The resampling method was great but ill choose that as second though the r.resamp.rst couldn't finish correctly, I used Slope from Raster Terrain Analysis from QGIS then r.resam.rst to get the output and the slope resampled with 200 cellsize.