# Avoiding too curly contours in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, contour, gdal-contour

I had point data in DXF and generated contours using QGIS. The contours had smaller islands and the contours in itself are too curly. I smoothed the contours too and I could avoid that unwanted island by rejecting contours of a certain length.

[image]

but how to avoid unwanted curliness in the single elevation contour. I am very new to QGIS and I don't know Python too. I have attached an image of part of my contour here. I have marked the curly contours with blue while I expect them to be straight as marked in red.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you can just use the simplify tool.

Comment: You might look at the Processing GRASS v.generalize tool, which has many different algorithms.  Being QGIS its easy to run the tool with one algorithm and different input parameters, look at the result, and try something else, since the results are temp.  I was mostly interested in reducing file size and drawing so I used the LANG method and then calculated lengths and deleted everything under a set size.  But that still can look rough depending on the scale you look at them.  If you are more interested in looks then you might try (before or after) the Vector Geometry smooth tool.

Comment: I'll add that if you still have the DEMs you could smooth them first and then create the contours.  Any smoothing (vector or raster) reduces the accuracy of course but that is your choice if it is worth it at the visual scale.  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346049/making-elevation-contours-of-raster-smoother-using-qgis

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Extract by expression lines over a certain length, I use 100 m: `$length>100` to remove the small rings
2. Simplify and smooth output with geometry by expression: `smooth(simplify( $geometry, 4), 20)`. Adjust 4 and 20.

Starting contours:
[image]

Length over 100:
[image]

Simplified and smoothed:

[image]

[image]

To answer your comment: Click the expression E, and search for the function to see the help. The 4 is max deviation and 20 is number of smoothing iterations:

[image]