# QGIS smooth geometry generator without success (no change at regional scale, only change at large scale)

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I am trying to smooth lines with geometry generator but without succes (at regional scale, only change at large scale )
Any help ? You will find the files in link.

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jxf4TmodAZuDNb4cY77W0qfhaa5_MMno/view?usp=sharing

Comment: 'Without success' is a little vague, what *actually goes wrong*? Do you get error messages, is your output turning into scribbles, do the geometries not change, does you computer catch fire or order takeaway without your consent....

Comment: It seems to be working properly. The problem could be that at the zoom scale at which you view the result you can't see the smoothing effect

Comment: See: [Avoiding too curly contours in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446676/avoiding-too-curly-contours-in-qgis/446688#446688)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try experimenting with the `offset` parameter of the `smooth` function.

###### From the docs

> *offset*
> value between 0 and 0.5 which controls how tightly the smoothed geometry follow the original geometry. Smaller values result in a tighter smoothing, larger values result in looser smoothing.

Result of `smooth($geometry, iterations:=7, offset:=0.3)`

[image]